# Kubuntu 20.04 language support configuration not saved

Tags: kubuntu, language-support

language support - version: 0.204 - source: ubuntu-focal-main (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Installing language support on Kubuntu Desktop 20.04 (64 bit) from Discover software centre (not the terminal).
Installation Starts

- a dialogue box titled "applying changes" states: "configuring language-pack..."
- at this point another dialogue box titled "debconf-kde-helper-kDialog <2>" opens which states: configuration file "//.config/debconf-kde-helperrc" not writable. Please contact your system administrator.

There may be other issues with configurations not being saved, as I have set 'one-click' to open folders and files, but after shutdown/restart it goes back to two-clicks again.

In Ubuntu 20.04 language support works without problem. So does the mouse one-click setting. But I have replaced Ubuntu with Kubuntu.

Comment: There is a very similar bug ticket in launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-runtime/+bug/1851573

Answer (score 1):

*Language Support* is not included in Kubuntu, and AFAIK it's not advisable to use it for language configuration on Kubuntu, which uses the KDE approach.

If you have previously used *Language Support* with your user, you may have the file `~/.pam_environment`, which you'd better remove on Kubuntu.

So I would suggest:

- Uninstall the `language-selector-gnome` package

  ```
   sudo apt purge language-selector-gnome
  ```
- Remove `~/.pam_environment`

  ```
   rm ~/.pam_environment
  ```
- Use the KDE tools for configuring languages

Comment: Thank you. I was under the impression language works in the same way in both gnome and KDE. I have removed Language Support via Discover software centre. I also tried the two lines of code you advised, however the result was there they were not installed.

Comment: @Sha: Since I don't use Kubuntu, I'm not able to provide details on how you should go about it instead. Please consult the Kubuntu documentation for that.

Comment: The language keyboards that I wanted to be able to type in other languages do work without the Language Support from software centre.
I was under the impression language works in the same way in both gnome and KDE. In this case perhaps if the two repositories of Ubuntu and Kubuntu were separated to remove from them what is not usable in each environment, it will be better for the none experienced user.

Comment: @Sha: Right, input languages is unrelated to Language Support anyway. Kubuntu is an Ubuntu flavor, which means that they share the same repo per se. Even if I see your point, separating them wouldn't be easy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general bug that affects some users when installing or updating; the issue is not limited to language packages.
It is reported for Ubuntu 20.04 over here

[configuration file //.config/debconf-kde-helperrc not writable](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptdaemon/+bug/1887432)

and for Ubuntu 19.10 over here

[configuration file //.config/debconf-kde-helperrc not writable](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-runtime/+bug/1851573)

The reported workaround is simply to create the missing file and set permissions. For instance, see comment 13 in the latter bug report:

[configuration file //.config/debconf-kde-helperrc not writable comment 13](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-runtime/+bug/1851573/comments/13)